In bash, how to one-line concatenate files into cin turned as argument to an executable?
In bash, how to one-line concatenate files into cin turned as argument to an executable?
Basically, I have this:
>> cat file.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  while(std::cin) {
    std::string line;
    getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

>> g++ -o file file.cpp 

>> cat file1.txt 
input

>> cat file2.txt 
output


And I need the file executable to output through cin the concatenation of file1.txt, and echo and file2.txt.
I need the output of file to be
>> ???what-to-do-here??? | ./file 
input
EOF
output

But I can't get it
>> cat < file1.txt | ./file 
input

>> cat < file1.txt <(echo "EOF") file2.txt | ./file 
EOF
output


EDIT
The purpose of the C++ program is to read files from cin, as in this case, I can not use argc / argv. I need to concat some kind of echo "EOF" in between the files to know when then file1 ends and where file2 begins.

I'm not sure I understand the question but fwiw, your C++ loop is wrong. It should be something like for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) { std::cout << line << '\n'; }

What's the purpose of the C++ program here really? It seems that you just want cat file1.txt && echo EOF && cat file2.txt or possibly cat file1.txt <(echo EOF) file2.txt or what am I missing?

Not sure what you want. cat already does concatenation. Is cat file1 file2 | ./file what you want?

Separately, prioritizing one-liners is a bad habit (and conflicts with our focus on "practical" questions). Worry about writing robust, correct code; if it fits in one line that's a bonus, but very often in bash (albeit not in this particular case) code written to be terse as its first priority often has subtle bugs.

If you took out the first <, by the way, you would have cat file1.txt <(echo "EOF") file2, which is fine. The < breaks things because it's an instruction to the shell, before cat starts, to open file1.txt and attach it to stdin; but when cat's argument list isn't empty it doesn't read stdin unless it's explicitly told to, which is why you don't see it in the output.

Regarding the edit: "I need to concat some kind of echo "EOF" in between the files to know when then file1 ends and where file2 begins" - Why? There is no need for it that you've shown. The buggy C++ program does nothing to help you with the task as you've described it.

I think this might be what you're trying to do:
cat file1.txt <(echo 'EOF') file2.txt | ./file

e.g. using an awk script in place of your C++ program for demo purposes:
$ cat file1.txt <(echo 'EOF') file2.txt | awk '{print}'
input
EOF
output


Assumptions:

general question is how to combine several outputs into a single input stream  to ./file
OP is not looking for assistance in debugging file.cpp / file

Setup:
$ cat testme
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    echo "stdin: $line"
done

One idea using braces:
$ { cat file1.txt; echo 'EOF'; cat file2.txt; } | ./testme
stdin: input
stdin: EOF
stdin: output

NOTES:

the opening brace ({) must be followed by a space)
the last command must be terminated with a ;
the closing brace does not need to be preceded by a space, ie, cat file2.txt; } and cat file2.txt;} are valid

This will perform all 3 operations regardless of the return status of each separate command. For example, if file1.txt does not exist this will generate:
$ { cat file1.txt; echo 'EOF'; cat file2.txt; } | ./testme
cat: file1.txt: No such file or directory
stdin: EOF
stdin: output

If you require stderr to also be fed into the single output stream then we can redirect stderr to stdin (2>&1):
$ { cat file1.txt; echo 'EOF'; cat file2.txt; } 2>&1 | ./testme
stdin: cat: file1.txt: No such file or directory
stdin: EOF
stdin: output

If you need each of the commands to only execute based on the success of the previous command you could chain them together with && but there's a catch:
$ cat file1.txt && echo 'EOF' && cat file2.txt | ./testme
input
EOF
stdin: output

Notice that only the output from cat file2.txt is prepended with stdin: ; this is because the | ./testme is considered part of the 3rd command, ie, bash sees this as:
command #1: cat file1.txt
command #2: echo 'EOF'
command #3; cat file2.txt | ./testme

Braces to the rescue:
$ { cat file1.txt && echo 'EOF' && cat file2.txt; } | ./testme
stdin: input
stdin: EOF
stdin: output

If cat file1.txt generates as error the follow-on commands are not executed:
$ { cat file1.txt && echo 'EOF' && cat file2.txt; } | ./testme
cat: file1.txt: No such file or directory

Adding edirection of stderr to stdout:
$ { cat file1.txt && echo 'EOF' && cat file2.txt; } 2>&1 | ./testme
stdin: cat: file1.txt: No such file or directory


This works:
>> cat file1.txt <(echo "EOF") file2.txt | ./file
input
EOF
output

But this doesn't
>> cat < file1.txt <(echo "EOF") file2.txt | ./file 
EOF
output

as the < after the cat breaks everything as mentioned in a comment.

keep in simple ... break into 2 separate cat calls and wrap in braces: { cat < file1.txt; cat <(echo "EOF") file2.txt; } | ./file
